# Spring java.time.LocalDateTime binding issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsr310

I have a domain object with properties below, upon form submission only the completionDate binds from the form input, while dateRaised is null. No errors except for validation errors. I tried changing the dateRaised type to java.time.LocalDate and it works fine. Is binding to java.time.LocalDateTime already supported?

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "date_raised", nullable = false)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
private java.time.LocalDateTime dateRaised;

@Column(name = "completion_date")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
private java.time.LocalDate completionDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the `AttributeConverter<EntityType, DatabaseType>` to convert your dates.

The following blog, [***Thoughts on Java***](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/) by [Thorben Janssen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3847917/thorben-janssen), explains how to store a `LocalDate` attribute in a `DATE` column or a `LocalDateTime` in a `TIMESTAMP` column.

> ## [How to persist LocalDate and LocalDateTime with JPA](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)
>
> JPA 2.1 was released **before** Java 8 and therefore **doesn't support** the new Date and Time API. If you want to use the new classes (in the right way), you need to define the conversion to `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` yourself. This can be easily done by implementing the `AttributeConverter<EntityType, DatabaseType>` interface and annotating the class with `@Converter(autoApply=true)`. By setting `autoApply=true`, the converter will be applied to all attributes of the `EntityType` and no changes on the entity are required.
>
> ```
> @Converter(autoApply = true)
> public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {   
>     @Override
>     public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
>         return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
>         return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The conversion of the attribute is **transparent to the developer** and the `LocalDate` attribute can be used as any other entity attribute. You can use it as a query parameter for example.
>
> ```
> LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, 8, 11);
> TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end", MyEntity.class);
> query.setParameter("start", date.minusDays(2));
> query.setParameter("end", date.plusDays(7));
> MyEntity e = query.getSingleResult();
> ```